# Caps Lock key mapped to a second Control key, reset after wake in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, settings

I'm running a clean install of Mountain Lion. I have my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key mapped to a second <kbd>Control</kbd> key.

Whenever I wake my computer back from sleep, it re-sets itself to the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key. This did not happen in Lion.

Has anyone else experienced this bug after upgrading?

Comment: Was this an issue in previous OS versions? Also, what keyboard are you using?

Comment: Same here. Worked with snow leopard, broke (i.e. not persistent across reboots anymore) after an update to mountain lion. Worked again after a fresh install of mountain lion, then suddenly broke again.

Comment: I am also experiencing this same issue

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on a 2010 MacBook Air with its internal keyboard. Not every time it wakes up, though. I did a clean install of Mountain Lion. I didn't have such an issue with Lion on the same machine.

Comment: i have the same problem. do you have Virtual Box installed?

Comment: I have the same problem and I do have Virtual Box installed

Answer (score 1):

This happens on all keyboards except the internal one. Maybe it doesn't "recognize" the keyboards as the same keyboards anymore.